# Interface require inheritance of base class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

I have elements of an interface. I want to use the proper function.
But because of the implements of function (I.F), it always use the base class function

Interface

```
Public Interface I
    Function F() As Boolean
End Interface
```

Base class implement of Interface I

```
Public MustInherit Class B
    Implements I

    Public Overridable Function F() As Boolean Implements I.F
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Classes using base class and will be used as object

```
Public Class C1
    Inherits B
    Public Overloads Function F() As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function
End Class

Public Class C2
    Inherits B    
End Class
```

Sample

```
Sub Main()
        Dim x As I
        x = New C1
        If x.F Then
            Console.WriteLine("c1 = true")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("c1 = false")
        End If

        x = New C2
        If x.F Then
            Console.WriteLine("c2 = true")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("c2 = false")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Result :

```
c1 = true
c2 = true
```

c1 should be false because of his own function "F".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to Overload it, you want to Override it:

```
Public Overrides Function F() As Boolean
    Return False
End Function
```

Overloading is when you want to have a different argument list.